# Sending unlimited files from client to server

Tags: java

So I have a homework from school wherein client must send unlimited files to the server. I made my idea like this.

1. Client will send unlimited files to the server.
2. Server will redirect files uploaded by the client to my wamp server folder

I have working code but this code can only send 1 file from client to server. I want also the file name of the uploaded files to increment because in my codes it only uses 1 file name, so if more clients uploaded their files they will overwrite the old file name.

For example: file01.rar next upload file02.rar and so on.

Here is my server code:

```
public void run() {
    filePath = "C:/wamp/www/file.rar";
    byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
    int bytesRead;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (is != null) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
            do {
                baos.write(aByte);
                bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
            } while (bytesRead != -1);
            bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (bos != null) {
                File uploadFile = new File(clientFacultyUploadTextField.getText());
                byte[] myFileSize = new byte[(int)uploadFile.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fife) {
                    fife.printStackTrace();
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                try {
                    bis.read(myFileSize, 0, myFileSize.length);
                    bos.write(myFileSize, 0, myFileSize.length);
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    clientFacultyUploadTextField.setText("Upload complete...");
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: First question on SO and such a nice formatting, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

When you send multiple files, you need to tell the server when one file stops and another file begins, so that it can handle them separately.

There are multiple ways to approach this problem. Here are some, ordered from easy but limiting to hard but impressive:

a) Use a new connection for each file, and close it when the transfer is completed. This tells the server that the file is over. The advantage of this is that you can easily extend it to allow simultaneous upload of multiple files at the same time. Drawback: When the transfer is interrupted for some reason, the server might not detect this as an error and save a partial file as if it were complete.

b) Use the same connection, but tell the server the length of each file. You could do this by starting each file transfer with the length of the file in bytes. That way the server can read this number of bytes and then start a new file. This, of course, only works when the filesize is known beforehand. It can't be used when you stream files which are still being created while the upload is in progress.

c) Use a framing protocol. Separate files into chunks, and prefix each chunk with a header which tells the server the length of the chunk and if it is the last chunk or if more chunks will follow. This method has some overhead, but it is a very extensible architecture which allows you to easily add new features by adding more information to the header. You could, for example, allow to multiplex multiple transfers over one connection by adding the ID of the transfer to the header, aborting and resuming uploads by adding a sequence number and control codes, special command-frames which tell the server to delete or rename files it already has, and much more. For some inspiration, look how HTTP and FTP work.

Comment: Im lost, where should i start? I guess your second solution was the best and easiest to do for me. Tell me if i'm doing the right thing or not. I will get the length of the file? then use a condition statement like if (file == fileSize)? then use like a boolean finish and set it to true? like that?